# gtk_tree_store how to add elements not rendered as columns

Tags: c, gtk

I am modifying a C/Gtk+ program that has a GUI with a list interface that presents a series of rows and columns backed up by a gtk_tree_store and a gtk_tree_view.

Based upon interaction with this program, I want to store additional values in the model/store alongside the existing rows/entries, however I don't want these values to be displayed in a column. There is no other existing data structure that contains these entries that I could use instead.

How can I add a "column" to a gtk_tree_view that I can set with gtk_tree_store_set but does not get rendered or presented as a column? Columns are currently being added with code that looks like this:

```
renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

g_object_set(
    renderer,
    "foreground",
    "white",
    NULL);


column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes (
    "ColX",
    renderer,
    "text",
    COLUMN_ID_X,
    "foreground",
    SOME_COLOR,
    "foreground-set",
    COLOR_SET_COLUMN,
    NULL);

gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree), column);
```

Answer (score 0):

To only store data without showing them in a [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) you only have to use the model (`GtkTreeStore`, `GtkListStore`, etc.), that is, do not add a column for that particular attribute in the model.

Here a slightly modified version of [gtk3-demo](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo/list_store.c) to show how to store 2 "columns" in a [GtkListStore](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html), but showing only one in the [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) (the *severity* column).  Pay attention to the functions `create_model` and `add_columns`.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

enum
{
  COLUMN_NUMBER,
  COLUMN_SEVERITY,
  NUM_COLUMNS
};

static GtkTreeModel *
create_model (void)
{
  GtkListStore *store;
  GtkTreeIter iter;

  store = gtk_list_store_new (NUM_COLUMNS,
                              G_TYPE_UINT,
                              G_TYPE_STRING);

  gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
  gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                      COLUMN_NUMBER, 1,
                      COLUMN_SEVERITY, "Normal", -1);

  gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
  gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                      COLUMN_NUMBER, 2,
                      COLUMN_SEVERITY, "Critical", -1);

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL (store);
}

static void
add_columns (GtkTreeView *treeview)
{
  GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
  GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (treeview);

  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Severity", renderer,
                                                     "text", COLUMN_SEVERITY,
                                                     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (treeview, column);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window = NULL;
  GtkTreeModel *model = NULL;
  GtkWidget *treeview;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 280, 250);
  g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  model = create_model ();
  treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (model);
  g_object_unref (model);

  add_columns (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview));

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), treeview);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```